# How to make the patch function work in PowerApps?

Tags: submit, patch, powerapps

I am currently working on a powerapps app, and I have multiple pages with forms and different SharePoint lists connected to it. But every code I tried for submitting the data to the SharePoint doesn‘t seem to be working. Does anyone have any ides?

```
Patch('5S Fragen_1';varFormData1; Form1.Updates; Form3.Updates; Form3_1.Updates; Form3_2.Updates; Form3_3.Updates; Form3_4.Updates; Form3_5.Updates; Form3_6.Updates; Form3_7.Updates;Form3_8.Updates;Form3_9.Updates;Form3_10.Updates;Form3_11.Updates; Form3_12.Updates;Form3_13.Updates;Form3_14.Updates;Form3_15.Updates;Form3_16.Updates;Form3_17.Updates;Form3_18.Updates;Form3_19.Updates;Form3_20.Updates;Form3_21.Updates;Form3_22.Updates)
```

5S Fragen_1 is the name of my SharePoint List and varFormData1 is the item name

Comment: how about you add some code to your question, otherwise your question will be closed with not enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to write Patch function in a different way:

```
Patch('5S Fragen_1';varFormData1; {Column1:textbox1.Text, Column2:Textbox2.Text, Column3Number:Value(Textbox3.Text)})
```

Alternatively, if you are using Forms, you can simply use `SubmitForm(FormName1);SubmitForm(Form2);` and so on.

***Explanation***: One way to write a  Patch function is:

```
Patch( DataSource, BaseRecord, ChangeRecord1 [, ChangeRecord2, … ])
```

**Datasource**: SharePoint, SQL, Dataverse, etc

**BaseRecord**: A "record" Type *object* in Power Apps.

```
LookUp(DataSource, ID = Value(Textbox1.Text))
```

or

```
{ID:Value(Textbox1.Text)}
```

or

```
First(DataSource)
```

or

```
Defaults(DataSource) - this creates a brand new record in your datasource
```

**ChangeRecord1**: What you want to change in that ***BaseRecord*** *object*

```
{
    Title: Box1.Text, //(or maybe ; instead of ,)
    Status: dropdown.Selected.Value
    //....
}
```

Comment: I have multiple pages that are connected to one SharePoint List, and at the end when I press the "submit" button it doesn't get updated in SharePoint with the patch function.
And the submitform function can't be used in this case

Comment: That's probably right, SubmitForm won't work. Have you tried to use the a patch function similar to this one? Patch('5S Fragen_1';LookUp('5S Fragen_1';Id = yourID) ; {Column1:textbox1.Text, Column2:Textbox2.Text, Column3Number:Value(Textbox3.Text)}. Started with a few columns and see if that works

Comment: What do you mean by yourID?

Comment: The Id of the SharePoint item you are editing. If you are creating a new item, replace LookUp('5S Fragen_1';Id = yourID) with Defaults('5S Fragen_1')

Comment: I tried this now, but I still don't get any values shown in my SharePoint list... idk I'm probably missing something somewhere

Comment: Quick update: I think I found my mistake, I now created a new SharePoint List, with no mandatory fields, and it's working. Although It would be nicer if it worked with mandatory fields too.

Comment: Awesome! Yea, with mandatory fields you'd have to ensure every mandatory column is incuded in your patch. 

I sometimes have no mandatory field at all in SP and "make fields mandatory" in Power Apps by disabling the save button if the mandatory TextInput around the screen are not filled

Comment: Now I have a question about that, I have a Star Rating in my app and I want to disable the save button when there's no Input in the Rating. I did it like this: If(Form9_3.Valid; DisplayMode.Edit; Disabled) , but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: What sort of Power Apps component are you using for the rating? Is that the slider? You might have to use a different conditional there rather than Form9_3.Valid, maybe something related to the Star Rating

Comment: Also, that might be a new question on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I used the normal Rating with those stars, not the slider. I posted a new question on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Another question: Do you know if it's possible to create a column in SharePoint that's just for the attachments (eg. for each question in the quiz a person can also upload a picture)? For now there is just one Attachment field that gets automatically created, but I didn't find a way to add more of those... I saw something with using Power Automate, but that didn't really work for me

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can only have 1 attachment column in a list. A workaround would be to have a document library to store files for you